# Cognos Security at #prompt Token#

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi

I am working on cognos 10.2 and our company had 4 servers located in different places, all the servers are OLTP and have the same schema and tables, which catch transaction data of sales in different locations,

Question

By using #prompt token # i am able to create a single package where i can connect to the different servers and fetch the data for the servers at a particular execution, but i want to give the security at this point where when i run the cognos report it will prompt for the datasource connection, at this point it should check for the users does he fall under the same group or he got the required permissions

for example

A , B, C, D are the different servers / datasource
A1, A2, A3   users/groups
B1, B2       users/groups
C1, C2       users/groups
D1           users/groups

when A1 run cognos report and selects  datasource as A then the report should execute, if he selects datasource a B it should not execute or should give a error message.

What are the steps or functions do i need to follow to create a package/ report

Thanks very much

Anil RG

Comment: Should user A1 **ever** be able to access data from B, C or D?

Comment: No, user A1 should not access data from any of the Servers B, C, D

Comment: Have you tried following the steps in [this IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21342840)? If so, what is giving you difficulty? It seems like your requirements are an exact match for that situation.

Comment: Thanks very very much, i will inform my DB admin to create a database and will follow the steps.